# Generating conditions on $b$ $\in$ $(0,1)$ s.t. $a^{1/b}$ $>$ $0$ $\forall$ $a$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ \ {$0$}?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Consider the expression $a^{1/b}$ .

I want to ensure that this expression results in a positive number by choosing the value $b$ myself, i.e. $a^{1/b}$ > $0$. I assume that $a$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ \ {$0$} and $b$ $\in$ $(0,1)$, i.e.
$a$ is a non-zero real and $b$ lies on the open interval between $0$ and $1$. I want to generate conditions of $b$ under which the expression $a^{1/b}$ > $0$.

Obviously if $a$ $>$ $0$ then $a^{1/b}$ > $0$ $\forall$ $b\in(0,1)$. But $a$ doesn't have to be strictly positive. If $a$ is strictly negative then $a^{1/b}$ > $0$ if $1/b$ $\in $ even $\mathbb{N}$. To my knowledge the only values of $b$ that will satisfy this are $b$ = $1/2^n $ $\forall$ $n\in\mathbb{N}$ $>=$$1$.

So my question is, can I generate conditions on $b$ such that the property $a^{1/b}$ > $0$ will hold always, or will the condition that $b$ = $1/2^n $ $\forall$ $n\in\mathbb{N}$ $>=$$1$ have to suffice to show $a^{1/b}$> $0$? Certainly $1/b$ doesn't **have** to be an even natural for $a^{1/b}$ > $0$ to hold, right? After all if $b=3/4$ then $1/b=4/3$ and $a^{1/b}$ $>$ $0$ $\forall$ $a$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ \ {$0$}  By conditions I'm referring to properties of $b$ like which sets it belongs to. Since $b$ $\in$ $(0,1)$ , $b$ can't be an integer which was my first thought, so then I started researching if properties of evenness and oddness can be extended to the rational numbers and if there might be some way that I could exploit such 'even' or 'odd' rational numbers to show that the reciprocal will result in an 'even-like' number that isn't a natural but none-the-less evaluates the entire expression to a positive.

Is the answer that $b$ must satisfy $b$ = $c/d$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Q}$ where $d$ must be even and $c$ must be odd? Is this the least restrictive condition necessary to show $a^{1/b}$ > $0$ or just sufficient?

Comment: Does $\Re$ mean the set of reals?

Comment: I think using polar coordinates makes your reasonings a lot clearer. If $a$ is negative, then $a=re^{i\pi}$ for some $r>0$. It is a bit more usefull to write $a=re^{i(1+2l)\pi}$ for some $l\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $a^{1/b}=r^{1/b}e^{i(1+2l)\pi/b}$ and for this to be positive, we must have $(1+2l)/b=2k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}_0$ or $b=(1+2l)/2k$ (i.e. odd/even)

Comment: @Anton I never thought to use polar coordinates but I see this now thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question makes use of complex numbers. Any negative real can be written as $a=re^{i\pi}$ for some $r>0$.

Then $a^{1/b} = r^{1/b} e^{i\pi/b}$. If $a^{1/b}>0$ then $r^{1/b} e^{i\pi/b}>0$ which is true **if and only if** $\frac{\pi}{b} = 2 \pi k$ for some integer $k$. This means that $b = \frac{1}{m}$ for any positive even integer $m$, since you also require $b\in(0,1)$.

So any positive, even denominator works. Not only a power of $2$. But for example $${(-1)}^{4/3} = e^{\frac{4}{3}i\pi} = \cos(\frac{4\pi}{3}) + i \sin(\frac{4\pi}{3}) = -\frac12 - i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},$$ which is not a real number.

---

Edit: Replying to a comment

There is an issue here that stems from the fact that complex roots are multivalued. Any negative number can be written as $a=re^{(2l+1)\pi i}$ and thus, if $b=\frac{2l+1}{2k}$ for some integers $k,l$, then $a^{1/b} = r^{1/b}e^{2k\pi i} = r^{1/b}>0$. However, this is one of the many ($2l + 1$ in this case) values of $a^{1/b}$.

So if you want to answer the question "For what values of $b$ it is true that for all $a<0$, **at least one of the** values of $a^{1/b}$ is positive?" then the answer is any number $b\in (0,1)$ such that $b=x/y$ with $x$ odd and $y$ even. Indeed, one of the 3 values of $(-1)^{4/3}$ is $1$.

If $x=1$, as in my original answer above, then we don't have a root anymore, and the only value of $a^{1/b}$ is positive. I believe this answers your original question more accurately, which is why I answered as I did.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could Anton V. also be correct in his comment above when he states that b must be an odd number over an even number, where both numerator and denominator are naturals and numerator < denominator to satisfy $b$ $\in$ $(0,1)$? In your answer $b$ $=$ $1/m$ which I agree is sufficient but could any odd natural number in numerator and even natural number in denominator work as long as numerator<denominator, as opposed to just 1 in numerator? Thanks again

Comment: @SaunchezDawggy Isn't $b=3/4$ one such number? In the calculation above you can see that $(-1)^{4/3}$ isn't positive. I've included the explanation to this question in the answer above via an edit, because it's too long for a comment.

Comment: Right right understood I see that now thank you